# Second order system - find -3dB frequencies and magnitude response analytically

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, laplace-transform

Let's take some simple second-order system like
$H(s) = \frac{j\omega T}{(1+ j \omega T)^2} $.
I know that the magnitude response is simply the absolute of the function and the -3dB frequencies can be found by solving for $|H(s)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
But I can't figure out how to analytically solve for $\omega$.  No matter how I try to solve, I find myself in a dead end with $\omega ^3$ or $\omega ^4 $.

So how would be the correct approach look like here?

Comment: Are you sure you end up with ${\omega}^{3}$ or higher order terms?

Comment: Yes, when I expand the denominator and multiply with the conjugate-complex. Something along $(1 + \omega ^2 T ^2 + j2\omega T )(1 + \omega ^2 T ^2 - j2\omega T)$

Comment: Or you can do it simply avoiding all that: $|{(1+j\omega T)}^{2}| = {|1+j\omega T|}^{2}=(1+j\omega T)(1-j\omega T)$ I guess you did a mistake out there plus you had to take the square root of the expression you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice:
>
> For the $-3$ dB points, you know that $\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and we can say that:
>
> $$\color{red}{20\log\left(\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|\right)=20\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-10\log(2)\approx-3.0103}$$
>
> Where $\log$ is the base $10$ logarithm.

---

First, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$|z|=\left|\Re[z]+\Im[z]i\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2[z]+\Im^2[z]}$$

So, in your problem (assuming $j^2=i^2=-1$ and $\text{T}\space\wedge\space\omega\in\mathbb{R}$):

- $$\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|=\left|\frac{j\omega\text{T}}{\left(1+j\omega\text{T}\right)^2} \right|=\frac{\left|j\omega\text{T}\right|}{\left|1+j\omega\text{T}\right|^2}=\frac{\omega\text{T}}{1+\left(\omega\text{T}\right)^2}$$

Now:

$$\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\omega\text{T}}{1+\left(\omega\text{T}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{2}\omega\text{T}=1+\left(\omega\text{T}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow-\text{T}^2\omega^2+\sqrt{2}\omega\text{T}-1=0$$

To solve this, use the quadratic formula:

$$-\text{T}^2\omega^2+\sqrt{2}\omega\text{T}-1=0\Longleftrightarrow\omega=\frac{1\pm i}{\text{T}\sqrt{2}}$$

So, we can conclude: there are no $-3$ dB points in the real plane!

---

Now, to solve $\omega$ out of $\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|$ :

$$\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|=\frac{\omega\text{T}}{1+\left(\omega\text{T}\right)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\omega\text{T}=\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|\left(1+\left(\omega\text{T}\right)^2\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\omega\text{T}-\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|\omega^2\text{T}^2-\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|=0$$

Again, use the quadratic formula:

$$\omega=\frac{\text{T}\pm\sqrt{\text{T}^2\left(1-4\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|^2\right)}}{2\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|\text{T}^2}$$

Assuming that $\text{T}\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

$$\omega=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|^2}}{2\text{T}\left|\text{H}(\omega)\right|}$$

---

**The quadratic formula**

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$